# Aligning image vertically in Word vertically

Tags: microsoft-word

When an image is pasted into a document, it will be be treated as a character so it will be aligned to the baseline.

What I want is to align it so that if it occurs in a bullet list, the bullet will be aligned to the top of the image.

How do I do that?

Actual behavior

[image: actual behavior]

Desired behavior

[image: preferred behavior]

Comment: [Is this what you are looking for?](https://wordribbon.tips.net/T009827_Vertical_Alignment_of_an_Inline_Graphic.html)

Comment: I tried it but could not find the "font dialog box"

Comment: [how about this?](https://i.imgur.com/Yw83TDJ.png)

Comment: I managed to lower the image with this technique. I will try to find another method because it requires testing and will not be exact.

Comment: Try to use Shift+Enter to start a new line for this picture as a workaround.

Comment: It seems like shift-enter does not produce a new paragrah, so I will not get another bullet. Only enter seems to produce an extra bullet (and also a gap above the image). There will be one bullet above+the gap+the image having the other bullet being at the left of the image and at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a table, with the bullets in one column and the image or text in another. Then set cell alignment to top: Table Properties>Cell>Vertical alignment>Top.

It would probably be easiest to use a bullet symbol rather than a bullet style. That way you could use the same paragraph style for both the bullet and the image or text.